# Bash user input while doing other stuff in background

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a while loop while waiting for user input.

```
read x
while [ $x == 3 ]
do
echo yay
done
```

does not do what I want. Of course it does not work, but I type that and make sure no one gets confused

Comment: It's not clear what you were hoping that this code should do. You can run the `while` loop in the background if you start it with `&` before the `read`, but of course a separate background process has no way to know which value the user inputs in the parent process.

Comment: See my answer below. Similar to your idea. But I figured it out myself at last. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out.

```sh
loop(){ while true; do echo -n .; sleep 2; done; }
loop & read x
kill %1
```

This defines a function called loop, runs it in background, waits for user input, then stops the background process.